# Cordova - Android. Admob doesn't appear

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm beginner in cordova. I would like to know why admob doesn't appear in the 'view'?

the admob code is fine.. it works in java code(I tested in another app too). What is wrong with this code?

My cordova main activy

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import org.apache.cordova.*;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import com.cordova.android.R;

public class cordova extends CordovaActivity 
{
public FrameLayout.LayoutParams adParams;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try{
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
}
```

And the view code html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menuDiv">Jhonatan</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to show admob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android mainifest file paste below code:

```
<!-- Add Mob Activity  -->
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                                                                 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```